# How do I get the dimensions of an image whose src is dynamically filled by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, attr

Suppose I have an empty placeholder `<img>` tag that I want to populate dynamically. I call `$("img").attr("src", "somephoto.jpg")` to point the element to the correct image. However, then I want to do something based on this image's width, but both `$("img").width()` and `$("img").attr("width")` return 0.

How can I get the width of the image---or better yet, is there a way to dynamically set the src of an image that is better practice and would solve my problem?

Comment: Is the image free-floating or do you insert it into the DOM?

Comment: I actually insert it initially but then keep changing the image. However, I use images of different dimensions and need to scale them; this is why I need a way to find the widths on-the-fly.

Comment: plenty of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+size+jquery

Answer (score 0):

I would personally append the entire new image rather than using an empty img tag's src attribute.

How are they returning zero? Remember that these two methods will return a string representation of the width, ie "10px", and not the integer 10.

Comment: Even then, until the Image's `onload` event fires, you can't read the height and width, because the browser doesn't know them.  Also, `img.height` and `img.width` are indeed Numbers.  The img.style.height and img.style.width are strings.

Comment: Given that the original poster's question uses __jQuery__, I referring to `$("img").attr("width")` and `$("img").width()` which return __strings__.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the image to load first.

```
$("img")
  .attr("src", "somephoto.jpg")
  .on("load", function () {
    alert(this.height()+" "+this.width())
  })
```

My jQuery might be a bit rusty.  Here it is in plain ol' JS

```
var i = new Image()
i.src = "somephoto.jpg"
i.onload = function () {
  alert(this.height + " " + this.width)
}
```

Comment: You mean `.one` instead of `.on`, right? Also, you'd need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object: `$(this).height()`

Comment: jQuery does not have an 'on' method. .bind or .load

Comment: @sunn0: jQuery does have a `.one()` method which does an unbind after the handler fires the first time, which would make sense for a `load` handler. Not sure if that's what @isaacs is after though.